# GoogleMaps in ABS - Xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2, xamarin-studio

I have a class to create a fragment containing a map, but the following error is occurring:

**Error inflating class fragment**

My LayoutMap.axml file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />`
```

My Activity_TabMap:

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated (saveInstanceState);

        _mapaFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance ();

        GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(FragmentManager.FindFragmentById (Resource.Id.map))).Map;

        googleMap.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;

    }

    public override  View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.LayoutMap, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Is the back-tick at the start of your layout intentional?

Comment: The backtick was to be edited by the forum code. Not part of the code :)